# How can I access veto messages?

Tags: united-states, congress, veto

On [senate.gov](https://www.senate.gov/reference/Legislation/Vetoes/Presidents/HooverH.pdf), there is a list of vetoes made by President Hoover:

For each veto, there is a reference to the veto message made. For example, on H.R. 12445, it says:

> Vetoed July 11, 1932. The veto message was laid
>   before the House, referred to the Committee on Ways
>   and Means, and printed as H.R. Doc. No. 360. (75
>   Cong. Rec. 15040, 15041).

I would like to access this veto message for research, but I don't know how to get to it. Is it open to the public?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Government Printing Office (GPO)](https://www.gpo.gov/) has digitized much of the Congressional Record. A search there will bring you to a page like this [one](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/search/pagedetails.action?collectionCode=GPO&granuleId=GPO-CRECB-1932-pt14-v75-3&packageId=GPO-CRECB-1932-pt14-v75&fromBrowse=true) where you will find the CR for July 11, 1932. On pages 15040-41, the explanation is given:

> *To the House of Representatives:*
>
> I am returning herewith, without my approval, H. R. 12445, " Emergency
>   relief and construction act of 1932."
>
> On the 31st of May last I addressed the Senate recommending further
>   definite and large-scale measures to aid in relief of distress and
>   unemployment imposed upon us by the continued degeneration in the
>   world economic situation. These proposals were made after discussion
>   with leaders of both political parties in Congress and in endeavor to
>   secure united nonpartisan action....

Answer (score 6):

It tells you that it is available in

- H.R. Doc. No. 360.  I believe that number is specific to the 1931-2 Congress.
- Which is printed in "75 Cong. Rec. 15040, 15041".
  The Congressional Record is a publication.  You should be able to go to a US library and take out Rec. 15040, 15041 of the Congressional Record for the 75th Congress.  They may not let you take it out of the library, but they should let you read it in the library.
- The date should be on or soon after July 11, 1932.

Since 1995 the [Congressional Record](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record) is online, so you could look there for recent messages.  But for this older stuff, I think that you would need to find the actual publication.

If you are in the United States, call your local library and ask them where such documents would be kept locally.  I would expect most major cities to have at least one library with a copy of the Congressional Record.  You also might check the local law school.

If there's nothing local to you, there may be an interlibrary loan program that would photocopy the relevant portion for a fee.

If all else fails, call the [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/) and ask them.

Comment: Many university libraries will have a dedicated government documents librarian. They would be a great reference.